# org.apache.jasper.JasperException error

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat

I am getting the following error.

- I am using MyEclipse Bling 10.1
- Deployed on Tomcat
- MS SQL 2008 R2

The code works fine when I do the same in MS SQL 2000. I want to where I am doing wrong.

```
    HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /uservalidation.jsp at line 16

13: 
14: 
15: Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
16:             Connection con5=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:web");
17:             PreparedStatement st1=con5.prepareStatement("select * from login where username=? and pass=?");
18:             st1.setString(1,un);
19:             st1.setString(2,ps);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:524)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.uservalidation_jsp._jspService(uservalidation_jsp.java:109)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3073)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    org.apache.jsp.uservalidation_jsp._jspService(uservalidation_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.13 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a good idea to try Googling the root cause. In this case "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" and the first result gives you the answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

check your jsp syntax. it may not show any error in eclipse but check it manually any missing brackets or any thing wrong in jsp syntax cause this problem